# Navigation between actvities that contain the same DataModel

Tags: java, android

I have an app that which loads a recyleView and creates some views into it that includes some songs names, for example. 
when I click the row, it opens an activity with more details about the song.
I have some left and right arrow buttons below the song, which I want will show the screen at the time with different details (about the song of the view below and above the view that was clicked in the begining respectively to the arrow-buttons).
I thought of starting the same song activity again(with different extra to show the details of the other song), and finish the one that was started in the begining.
I think that it is a bad practice.

The problem in my mind, is that whenever I open the activity with the recycleView, I load all of the songs and store it in an arraylist, but when I start the activity of the detailed song, I lose the array list, so how can I save this songs arraylist when I start the activity, everytime I open it?
In general, how can I change the song details when I press the button, without opening a different activity?

I have a little concern because the details are also in the toolbar, and I request the song data from a server, so it might not look nice.

Edit:

AsyncTask (from the main activity)

```
        private class LauncherSongs extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

//            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            mAdapter = new SongsRcAdapter(mSongsList, getApplicationContext());
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Song");
            query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(List<ParseObject> songs, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
                            ParseObject object = songs.get(i);

                            String songName = object.getString("name");
                            String poetName = object.getString("poetName");
                            Date dateSong = object.getDate("pushDate");

                            String LetterOfTheDate = Utils.DateToFirstDayletter(dateSong.toString());
                            String DateToNumbers = Utils.toNumbersDate(dateSong);

                            SongModel s = new SongModel(poetName, songName, LetterOfTheDate, DateToNumbers);
                            mSongsList.add(s);
                        }
                        mAdapter.changeData(mSongsList);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("error", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
//            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
```

The song Class: (some code just don't relevant so deleted those parts)

```
public class song extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView poetNameTV, songNameTV, songContenct;
    private TextView TB1, TB2;

    public Toolbar mToolbar;
    public NestedScrollView mScrollView;
    public FloatingActionButton fab;
    public boolean scrooling;
    public AppBarLayout RL;
    public Typeface face;
    public CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
public  FloatingActionMenu FAMenu;
    //    for swap
    float x1, x2;
    float y1, y2;

    public int position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_song_test);


        initFAB();


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setShowHideAnimationEnabled(true);

         FAMenu = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.FAMenu);
        FloatingActionButton ButtonFAM1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.textBig);


        FAMenu.setClosedOnTouchOutside(true);


        mScrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        poetNameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Poet);
        songNameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameSong);
        songContenct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songContenct);

        songContenct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        poetNameTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        songNameTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeScroll);


//        Getting the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String SongName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
//        String poetName = intent.getStringExtra("poet");
        position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);

        Log.e("*************", String.valueOf(position));


        mToolbar.setTitle(SongName);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Song");
        query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> songs, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    ParseObject object = songs.get(position);
                    String songName = object.getString("name");
                    String poetName = object.getString("poetName");
                    String songC = object.getString("text");
                    songContenct.setText(songC);
                    poetNameTV.setText(poetName);
                    songNameTV.setText(songName);

                    songContenct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    poetNameTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    songNameTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("error", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        songContenct.setTypeface(face);
        poetNameTV.setTypeface(face);
        songNameTV.setTypeface(face);

        mScrollView.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
        mScrollView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

        mScrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    }




}
```

Comment: Can you post how you retrieve and populate your recyclerview with the song data and how you open your details activity?

Comment: I populate the data using an AsyncTask, I retrieve it from a parse server. 
when I click the view, I make an intent, put there an extra of the song name and song poet, for example. when I open the details activity, I retrieve again the detailed data about the song from the server using AsyncTask again. Any ideas? @MuchOverflow

Comment: I think the issue can be sorted in different ways. It will be easier for me if you can post the code here so I can find what exactly needs to be done if I can :)

Comment: HI, it's really long code :) what are the options you have in you mind? I'd know how to tail it to my case. thank you! @MuchOverflow

Comment: well, you could store your data in the bundle during savedInstanceState lifecycle or you can use SQLite db to store whatever you retrieve and reuse or else you can have singleton ViewModel class that lives throughout your app "session" and use it to store retrieved data..

Comment: Thank you. I though about the SQLite DB solution. can you please explain a little bit more about the singelton ViewModel and the savedinstanceState? I have never hear about the viewmodel idea, and I can't think of a way to implement the savedinstanceState to solve it. I updated and uploaded the song details class and my asyncTask from my main activity. @MuchOverflow

Comment: Do check it here https://github.com/inloop/AndroidViewModel